# Specify Event Date in New Event Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-calendar

I'm building a jQuery Full Calendar page to add additional functionality to the stock Calendar. I'm having trouble mimicking default calendar behavior.

When clicking the `+Add` link on a date, I can't set the new event's Start Date (it defaults to today). I'd like to handle this the same way as the default calendar (using JavaScript, I assume).

What I DON'T want to do is pass a query parameter and customize `NewForm.aspx` to parse that information. I'd like all customization to be on my one Full Calendar page.

Default SharePoint behavior. It set the Start Time to August 8 when clicking the `+ Add` button on August 8 for the calendar.
[image: Default SharePoint behavior]
This is the behavior of my calendar. It sets the Start Time to today's date despite clicking the `+ Add` button on the August 8 button. There is currently no code to actually set the calendar date in my calendar, as I can't find anywhere that explains how to accomplish this (short of a custom `NewForm.aspx`). Trying to trace SharePoint JavaScript is also very difficult.
[image: My calendar behavior]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot

Comment: Updated to include images.

Comment: You could try and dig in the SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.debug.js file for how its done, but probably easier to attach a small script to the form yourself even if you don't want to do that :)